# Transparent JButton still painting its background

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, translucency, awtutilities

I have a **translucent** JPanel. I have created a **custom JButton** by extending JButton as I required a button with rounded corners and wanted to add some effects to it. I have made the button **non-opaque**. When I add this button to my translucent JPanel it apears fine. But on rollover a black patch is painted behind the button which looks really crappy. I searched the net for a solution but could'nt find a useful one . This problem is also described at  http://www.java.net/node/661798 but i was not able really make kirillcool's suggestion work out.....Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you tried to download/use another look & feel instead of writing your own? I used synthetica in my last project, and it was quite good and "fancy"

Answer (score 7):

I believe you need to add:

```
button.setContentAreaFilled( false );
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if someone is still interested...
you can fix the problem by overriding the `paintComponent()` method to let Java draw the `JButton` in any Shape you like. you just need to set the background of the Graphics object to transparent with `setBackground()` method. also you need to clear the Graphics object BEFORE drawing on it with `clearRect()` method and then fill it again with the alpha level of the background of your `JButton`. here is my piece of code.. it shows the overriden `paintComponent()`. by pasting it into your `JButton` you should get a `JButton` with rounded edges even if its on semi-transparant background

```
private int outerRoundRectSize = 10;
private int innerRoundRectSize = 8;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    int h = getHeight();
    int w = getWidth();

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    Color GP = null;

    //////////////get rid of the black background////////////////////////
    g2d.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0.0f));
    g2d.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    g2d.setPaint(new Color(0,0,0,0.3f));
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    //////////////get rid of the black background////////////////////////

    ButtonModel model = getModel();
    if(!model.isEnabled()) 
    {
        setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        GP = new Color(0.5f,0.2f,0.6f);
    }
    else
    {
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        if(model.isRollover()) 
        {
            GP = new Color(0.5f,0.2f,0.6f);
        } 
        else 
        {
            GP = new Color(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
        }   
    }
    g2d.setPaint(GP);
    Color p1 = null;
    Color p2 = null;

    if(getModel().isPressed()) 
    {
        GP = new Color(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        g2d.setPaint(GP);
        p1=new Color(0.12f,0.7f,0.3f);
        p2=new Color(0.7f,0.5f,0.6f);
    } 
    else 
    {
        p1=new Color(0.0f,0.5f,0.7f);
        p2=new Color(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        GP = new Color(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    }

    RoundRectangle2D.Float r2d = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, w - 1, h - 1, outerRoundRectSize, outerRoundRectSize);
    Shape clip = g2d.getClip();
    g2d.clip(r2d);
    //g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, outerRoundRectSize, outerRoundRectSize);
    g2d.setClip(clip);
    g2d.setPaint(p1);
    g2d.drawRoundRect(0, 0, w - 1, h - 1, outerRoundRectSize,outerRoundRectSize);
    g2d.setPaint(p2);
    g2d.drawRoundRect(1, 1, w - 3, h - 3, innerRoundRectSize,innerRoundRectSize);

    g2d.dispose();
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: don't write custom code when configuring a single property does the thrick :-) btw: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.